# "Make this your Default Search engine" button?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Whats code for making my website the default search engine ?

For example, as you can see on http://www.dogpile.com/

"Add dogpile to your browser"

I have a site www.searchr.us

I want to add a same thing.  But I'm unable to understand how to make it.  Is there any tutorial?

And will the code which you provide work on any browser ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the source reveals:

```
function addSearch(url) {
    try {
         if(null != url) {
             window.external.AddSearchProvider(url);
         }
    }
    catch (e) {
        // do nothing
    }
    return false;
}
```

It is related to [OpenSearch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox):

> To install an OpenSearch plugin, you need to use the `window.external.AddSearchProvider()` DOM method. The syntax for this method is:
>
> ```
>     window.external.AddSearchProvider(engineURL);
> ```
>
> Where `engineURL` is the absolute URL to the XML file for the search engine plugin.

or for auto-discovery:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="searchTitle" href="pluginURL">
```

See the [official website](http://www.opensearch.org/Home) of OpenSearch.

Answer (score 2):

All that button does is return an [OpenSearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch) description file. What to do with that is up to the browser; I guess most will add the described search engine to their list of shortcut search engines.